# Firebase Database in Unity with REST API

Tags: unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create a connection to the Firebase Realtime Database by following this tutorial: https://medium.com/@rotolonico/firebase-database-in-unity-with-rest-api-42f2cf6a2bbf to understand how it works and modify as I go. However, I am getting the following errors (these are just some of the errors):

```
Assembly DLL name is reserved for internal use: Assets/UnityEngine.dll (did files generated by a build accidentally end up in your Assets/ folder?)

C:\Program files\2019.4.20f1\Editor\Data\Resources\PackageManager\BuiltInPackages\com.unity.ugui\Runtime\UI\Core\FontData.cs(135,16): error CS0433: The type 'TextAnchor' exists in both 'UnityEngine.TextRenderingModule, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'UnityEngine, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'`

C:\Program Files\2019.4.20f1\Editor\Data\Resources\PackageManager\BuiltInPackages\com.unity.ugui\Runtime\UI\Core\InputField.cs(241,10): error CS0433: The type 'SerializeField' exists in both 'UnityEngine.CoreModule, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'UnityEngine, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
```

These errors are populating when I did the following steps:

- Navigate to the `Build Files (DLL)` folder.
- Open `CommonData.csproj` in your favorite text editor.
- Change the `UnityInstallFolder` value on line 6 to point to your Unity installation directory

  - On OSX this is likely `/Applications/Unity/Editor`
  - On Windows this is likely `C:\Program Files (x86)\Unity\Editor`
- Double click `FullSerializer.sln` to open up the solution
- Run a build-all (F6 in visual studio). Alternatively, you can right-click any of the three projects to build only one of them.

  - `FullSerializer - NoUnity` builds Full Serializer so that you can use it outside of Unity.
  - `FullSerializer - Unity` builds Full Serializer to a DLL
  - `FullSerializer - Unity - WinRT` builds Full Serializer with WinRT APIs (if you're targeting the Windows Store or the Windows Phone export platforms)
- You will find the DLLs inside of the `Build` folder. Please add them to your Unity project's Asset folder.

Here is the path where unity is installed:
C:\Program Files\2019.4.20f1\Editor

I opened the FullSerializer.sln, and build one of the three projects, and so on.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to determine the issue. It appears that although the instruction suggests adding the source folder in the assets folder of the Unity Project, I remove it from there and put it in the same level as the assets folder. That resolved the issue. Hope this helps anyone else who has encountered this issue.